# Git Under TFS - Update Work items from Commit/Pull Request

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs

I have just recently started using Git under TFS after previously using TFS Source Control for years so just starting to get my head around the process flow.

One thing I am however unable to get my head round is how to resolve work items/bugs in TFS from Commits/Pull Requests.

Can anyone offer me any advice in how to achieve what was a very simple task with TFS Source Countrol.

We are using Visual Studio Team Services.

Thanks In Advance

Stuart

Comment: It is not supported for now. You can vote this feature request: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/6380299-update-work-items-on-commit-for-git

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can fix a work item from a pull request or a commit.

But you could link it easily using '#workitemId': https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/03/02/linking-work-items-to-git-branches-commits-and-pull-requests/

Comment: Thanks for this @Philippe, I was looking a bit more and found this and wondered if it was supported in TFS Git?

https://help.github.com/articles/closing-issues-via-commit-messages/

Comment: @StuartFerguson, No, TFS doesn't support this feature.